# Excel, counting within a formulatext on array

Tags: arrays, excel, count

Imagine rows A2:A11 = name of customer, Columns B1:AE1 = days of the month.

To make it easy:
Daily, we tally if customers purchase (quantity) and separate them with a + to get the total of that day purchase.  (example: on 2nd day of the month (C2:C5)

```
Abe =44+54+10

John =22+10+40

Sara =40

Mary=10+10
```

Also we need to count total “sales cases” of the whole day (in the above example it is 3+3+1+2)= 9 to show in the last row of the day. (B12 in this example)
The logic is something like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(FORMULATEXT(C2:C5))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(C2:C5),"+","")))
```

But I’m getting NA. 
reminder: when there are no "+" signs & the value is more than zero, it should count as 1.

help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a trick to do this, which might end up a bit convoluted to achieve the end result you want

First, define a new name in Name Manager (in the Formula menu bar)

Name: FormulaText
Refers to: `=GET.CELL(6,OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE),0,-1))`

Now if you have a formula in cell B3 of `=10+20+30` enter `=FormulaText` in cell C3 and you will get the text version of the formula

You can now count + symbols in that formula using `=LEN(C3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3,"+",""))`

In your specific circumstances, I would offset all of this to the right of your spreadsheet, say by 35 columns, in which case you will need to change the definition of FormulaText accordingly.

A fair bit of set-up work, but the result should work automagically.